# how to take large size array in java

Tags: java, arrays

i am new to java and i want to take large input size array in java. but in gives me some Runtime Error - NZEC, I don't know about it and i also did some research on this error but did'nt find anything related to my problem.

```
   long n=sc.nextLong();// n can be upto 10^9;
   long a[]=new long[n];// declaring array of n;
```

also i am facing a compile time error which is :

```
error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from long to int
```

can anyone please solve my this issue??

Comment: Which line causes exactly which error (complete stacktrace)? Please _edit_ the question and add all relevant information.

Comment: What exact Java error are you getting? Note that allocating space for such array might be difficult for Java / underlying OS, because not just that amount of memory must be free, but also there must be a continuous chunk of memory this big.

Answer (score 1):

Array sizes are limited to `int` size (i.e. about 2 billion). You're trying to initialize one with `long`. Either read the size into an `int` or cast the long with `long a[]=new long[(int)n];`.

I recommend the former to avoid any subtle bugs.

Comment: Casting the long to int could still cause the issue that the error is blocking you from. The only proper way of doing this is to never use a long for the size in the first place.

Comment: @Thiefster That's exactly why I recommended the first approach.

Answer (score 0):

The size of arrays in Java is of the type `int`. Since a `long` can hold more data than an `int` some data might get lost when converting from `long` to `int`.

Answer (score 0):

An array index cannot be specified with a long as you have done but only with an int as the array size is limited to Integer max value

But in your case it should not be a problem as Integer max value is `2^31-1.` (more than 2 billions)  and you requirement is inferior :`10^9` (1 billion).
 So it should be fine to replace :

```
   long n=sc.nextLong();// n can be upto 10^9;
```

by

```
   int n=sc.nextInt();// n can be upto 10^9;
```

Answer (score 0):

Array sizes are limited to int size in java. so you need to create your array with int sizes always. you have to take n as int. and replace the long `n=sc.nextLong();// n can be upto 10^9;` `by int n=sc.nextInt();// n can be upto 10^9;`

It will work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

To have such a large array may be inefficient in the first place. Can this be replaced with a better data structure that will help in your use case. May be the overall problem that is being attacked, if provided can help solve it in a different more efficient way.

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers suggested, array-indexes are `int`-based, and an array is probably not the right data structure for whatever it is you want to do.

Let's consider memory usage. An array has a 12 byte object header, followed by `n * v` bytes for the actual data (where `n` is the array size, and `v` the size of the type you're storing in it).

For example, let's consider the following array declaration:

```
long[] longArray = new long[Integer.MAX_VALUE];
```

A long has 64 bits, or 8 bytes. Integer.MAX_VALUE equals 2147483647. This means your array is going to take 17179869188 bytes, or in other words 17 GB of RAM.

Is it possible to create larger arrays? Definitely: you could make a multi-dimensional array (each additional dimension would multiply the available positions by up to Integer.MAX_VALUE), but the memory usage will be atrocious. Consider the following example:

```
long[] multiArray = new long[5][5];
```

This array has 25 positions, so by my earlier formula you might figure it takes `25 * 8 + 12` bytes, or `212` bytes, but a 2-dimensional array is an array of arrays, so each inner array also has an object header, so we're talking `(5 * 8 + 12) * 5 + 12` bytes, or `272` bytes. Now imagine doing this on larger levels.

```
long[] multiArray = new long[Integer.MAX_VALUE][Integer.MAX_VALUE];
```

This takes `(Integer.MAX_VALUE * 8 + 12) * Integer.MAX_VALUE + 12` bytes, or 3.689348813882917e19 bytes (36.89 exabytes, or 36.89 billion GB).

If you really need to work with those amounts of data, you  probably need a computing cluster, not an array.